# Understanding histogram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

OK I found this code of a histogram, I'm trying to understand how it works to be honest, an if there's an easier way to write out the code to do the same thing as its doing here but in a shorter way.

```
def histogram(array, start, stop, chart)
  (array.count {|array| array >= start and array <= stop}).to_s.rjust((chart))
end

array, stop, range, found, chart, start = [], 10, 1, 3, 2, 1

200.times do
  array.push(rand(1..100)).sort!
end

puts "  Range     #Found      Chart" "\n" " -------     ------    ------------------------------"
puts
print " 1 -  10      |#{histogram(array, start, stop, chart)}|     "
array.each do |counts|
  if counts > stop
    print "\n"
    start += 10
    stop += 10
    print "#{start.to_s.center(range)} "
    print "- #{stop.to_s.rjust(found)}      "
    print "|#{histogram(array, start, stop, chart)}|     *"
  else
    print "*"
  end
end
```

Comment: What part of this code is difficult to understand for you? For an explanation how specific methods (like `rjust`, `center`) work you may find help at `ruby-doc.org` or other sources of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I took the given code and re-wrote it with functions and what I consider to be more descriptive variable names; this has made it actually longer in terms of LoC, but should help you get your head around the structure. There's a lot more that could be done to improve it, but I've tried to preserve the functionality exactly.

```
def count_entries_in_bin(array, bin_min, bin_max, chart)
  (array.count {|entry| entry >= bin_min and entry <= bin_max}).to_s.rjust((chart))
end

def generate_random_ordered_data
  array = []
  200.times do
    array.push(rand(1..100)).sort!
  end
  array
end

def print_histogram_header
  puts "  Range     #Found      Chart"
  puts " -------     ------    ------------------------------"
  puts
end

def start_new_row(array, bin_min, bin_max)
  print "\n"
  print "#{bin_min.to_s.center(RANGE_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH)} "
  print "- #{bin_max.to_s.rjust(FOUND_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH)}      "
  print "|#{count_entries_in_bin(array, bin_min, bin_max, CHART_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH)}|     *"
end

RANGE_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH = 1
FOUND_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH = 3
CHART_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH = 2
bin_min = 1
bin_max = 10

array = generate_random_ordered_data
print_histogram_header
print " 1 -  10      |#{count_entries_in_bin(array, bin_min, bin_max, CHART_FIELD_MIN_WIDTH)}|     "
array.each do |entry|
  if entry > bin_max
    bin_min += 10
    bin_max += 10
    start_new_row(array, bin_min, bin_max)
  else
    print "*"
  end
end
```

Comment: You might consider generating random ordered array using `Array.new(200) { rand(1..100) }.sort`. It is better in terms of LoC and I think it should be easy to understand - it creates fixed size array and fills it with default values. Also it's probably faster (one allocation vs multiple) and avoiding bang ("dangerous") methods is an additional advantage.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip. Like I said, I was thinking about literally no aspect other than improving the clarity of the given code whilst preserving its methods.

Comment: Although if I *had* been trying to fix the code properly, I would have begun by writing something that works if your input array isn't sorted, for a start....